# How to call an action of controller from grids action column

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have an action column in my grid which is needed to perform lots of non-trivial operations after click on it. I don't want to use the handler method only to avoid duplicity in my code. I want to handle the click event from the controller method which can be called from more sides.

Here is my definition of action column:

```
{
    header: translator.translate('actions'),
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    width: 50,
    items:[{
        id     : 'detailContactPerson',
        icon   : '/resources/images/pencil.png',
        tooltip: translator.translate('show_detail')
    }]
},
```

But now I don't know how to write the Component query definition to set up listener.

```
 init: function() {
    this.control({
       'detailContactPerson': {
           click: function(obj) {
                 var contactPerson = obj.up('container').contactPerson;
                 this.detail(contactPerson);
            }
         },
```

Second way I've tried is to call the method of controller directly from handler method. It looks like this:

```
  {
    header: translator.translate('actions'),
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    width: 50,
    items:[{
        id     : 'detailContactPerson',
        icon   : '/resources/images/pencil.png',
        handler: function(contactPerson){
            Project.controller.contactPerson.detail(contactPerson);
        },
        tooltip: translator.translate('show_detail')
    }
```

But unfortunately it isn't supported way to call controller method (No method exception raised).

Could someone help me to construct working Component query, or show some example how to call controller method from outside?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try actioncolumn#detailContactPerson

or you can listene to actioncolumn 's click event

see this: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?131299-FIXED-EXTJSIV-1767-B3-ActionColumn-bug-and-issues

```
init: function() {
        this.control({
            'contact button[action=add]':{
                click: this.addRecord 
            },
            'contact button[action=delete]':{
                click: function(){this.deleteRecord()} 
            },
            'contact actioncolumn':{
                click: this.onAction
            }
        });
    },
    onAction: function(view,cell,row,col,e){
        //console.log(this.getActioncolumn(),arguments, e.getTarget())
        var m = e.getTarget().className.match(/\bicon-(\w+)\b/)
        if(m){
            //选择该列
            this.getGrid().getView().getSelectionModel().select(row,false)
            switch(m[1]){
                case 'edit':
                    this.getGrid().getPlugin('rowediting').startEdit({colIdx:col,rowIdx:row})
                    break;
                case 'delete':
                    var record = this.getGrid().store.getAt(row)
                    this.deleteRecord([record])
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

BTW.I prefer to use these to instead of AcionColumn

- [Ext.ux.grid.column.ActionButtonColumn](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?135880-Ext.ux.grid.column.ActionButtonColumn)
- [Ext.ux.grid.RowActions](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?137085-Ext.ux.grid.RowActions-Plugin-Updated-for-Ext-4.0.2)

Comment: Hi Atian. Thanks for reply. The first sentence (and lot of variation of it)  I've alredy tried. I think the problem is that the items of action column are not components. They are defined like simple array. This makes it imposible to get it using ComponentQuery. But I'm not sure, I'll ask devs of Sencha as soon as I'm in office. The "click event" way looks perfectly. I'll try it. Once more Thank you very much. I appreciate it.

Comment: yes,it's not a component. this.control can't access it. I don't like ActionColumn,and prefer to use plugin

Answer (score 8):

I have a better way: add new events on your view where are presents the actioncolumns:

```
    {
                xtype:'actioncolumn',
                align:'center',
                items:[
                    {
                        tooltip:'info',
                        handler:function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                            var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                            //this is the view now
                            this.fireEvent('edit', this, rec);
                        },
                        scope:me
                    },
    .... 
    me.callParent(arguments);
    me.addEvents('edit')
```

then on your controller:

```
 .....
 this.control({
         'cmp_elenco':{
                'edit':function(view,record){//your operations here}
 ....
```

Comment: Pending my edit that makes this a little easier to understand... I prefer this method of listening for an event.

Comment: This is the arity of arguments that the handler function is called with: view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row. As you can see record is already part of that. So you can `handler: function (view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row) { this.fireEvent('edit', this, record); }`

Answer (score 4):

I too wanted to handle logic for the `actioncolumn` in a controller. I am not certain if this is better or worse than simply using one of the other plugins mentioned, however this is how I was able to get it to work.

Things to note:

- the `id` config property in the `items` array of the `actioncolumn`
  does nothing at all, the icons will still receive a generated `id`
- the `items` are NOT components, they are simply img elements
- you can add an `id` to the `actioncolumn` itself to target a specific instance of actioncolumn
- each icon (or item in the `actioncolumn`) is given a class of `x-action-col-#` where # is an index beginning with 0.

For example, in the columns definition of my grid I have:

```
    header: 'ACTION',
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    id: 'myActionId',
    width: 50,
    items: [{
        icon: 'resources/icons/doThisIcon.png',
        tooltip: 'Do THIS'
      },{
        icon: 'resources/icons/doThatIcon.png',
        tooltip: 'Do THAT'
      }
    ]
```

and in the controller:

```
    init: function(){
    this.control({
        'actioncolumn#myActionId': {
           click: function(grid,cell,row,col,e){
               var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(row);
               var action = e.target.getAttribute('class');
               if (action.indexOf("x-action-col-0") != -1) {
                   console.log('You chose to do THIS to ' + rec.get('id')); //where id is the name of a dataIndex
               }
               else if (action.indexOf("x-action-col-1") != -1) {
                   console.log('You chose to do THAT to ' + rec.get('id'));
               }
           }
        }
    }
```

Using this method, you can place all logic for any given action column in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to avoid declaring the handler (no need to use `addEvents`, ExtJS 4.1.1) :

`Ext.grid.column.Action` override :

```
Ext.grid.column.Action.override({
    constructor: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        Ext.each(this.items, function () {
            var handler;
            if (this.action) {
                handler = this.handler; // save configured handler
                this.handler = function (view, rowIdx, colIdx, item, e, record) {
                    view.up('grid').fireEvent(item.action, record);
                    handler && handler.apply(this, arguments);
                };
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Action column config :

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    items: [{
        icon: 'edit.png',
        action: 'edit'
    }]
}
```

Controller :

```
this.control({
    'grid': {
        edit: function (record) {}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow this example http://onephuong.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/data-grid-action-column-in-extjs-4/.